# How to push messages alternating from 2 queues to workers in RabbitMQ or Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, messaging, amqp

To calculate a complex algorithm on a huge dataset we want to employ a MQ such as Kafka (or any other MQ like Activemq or AMQP) to host two queues each representing semantic different parts of the dataset. The messages originate from a web service that - based on two different user roles - puts them in the correct queue.

For horizontal scalability we deploy several workers to work on the queues and calculate partial results and also derive some overall result.

To prevent some problems with parallel computation we want all workers to similarly work either on queue1 or on queue2, but not mix working on them (because that would require tremendous amounts of locks and checks and additional db access to work on the queues interwinde).

Within a queue the order of computation is not strictly required but appreciated.

**First part:**

So, what we want to do is to tell the message broker to select as many messages from queue1 as there are workers online (let's say `x`) and let all the workers work on a message of the (same) queue. After these messages are acknowledged to be processed successfully (we may not loose a message) the broker now should select `x` messages from queue2 and push them to the workers.

**Second part:**

Since queue1 normally has much more messages we also want to implement a scheduling algorithm to do the above in a way so that both queues are evenly sized in average. Basically, we might to repeat selecting from queue1 several times and then switch over to queue2 based on comparing the sizes of the queues.

**Third part (bonus):**

Also we are unsure about where we should accumulate the results of the workers to push them to the DB. The decision will be based on ram usage but when needed, where should  the service sit in the architecture that pulls additional data for the current `x` messages from the DB and later puts the intermediate and final results back to the db?

**Final words**

Is that possible with Kafka or RabbitMQ or any other broker? Where should our scheduler sit from an architectural point of view?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at kafka. Probably the stream feature could help

Comment: Yes Kafka is on the list of tools as well, but maybe other smart people may have experience with such problem scenario. At least I could not find information and future people might find this SO as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Complex scheduling rules are better off your messaging infrastructure.

It would more flexible and simpler to implement this scheduler as a service that consumes messages from `queue1` and `queue2` in alternated batches, then re-queue those into a single work queue for your workers to consume.

This work queue must be long enough for your workers not to starve but short enough for your scheduler to alter the next batch ratio based on queue length (second part).

For your last *bonus* part, especially if the final results come from the aggregation of this data (as opposed to one result per original queue task) I see no reason why these workers cannot write the results to a database directly.

This should be possible with basically **any** message broker; Definitely possible with both RabbitMQ or Kafka.

Comment: In this approach: How could we ensure, that the work-queue is flushed (all messages acknoweldged) before any worker starts working on the next batch? We must guarantee that, in case a worker is slow, the next batch is not computed because it might result in an inconsistent state if another worker then outpaces the slow worker who is still working on the old batch. As far as I see the intermediate service would need to receive the ACKs of all services, but then we are kind of building our own broker which feels wrong.

Comment: And I don't see how consuming messages alternating from the original two queues is implemented. It kind of needs pause/resume functionality in the consumers, what is not necessarily supported by the brokers nor by the frameworks on top of them (e.g. Spring Cloud Stream).

Comment: When all workers have their own direct DB connection, this results in a lot of network traffic and single row inserts/updates instead of collecting the data on an intermediate service and then flush the results in one DB-transaction. Maybe kafka connect could be a solution?

Comment: @Stuck 1). the scheduling service would not care about ACKs, In AMQP, those would be just sent to the broker per work queue message. The scheduler can know the batch is done because the work queue is empty. 2). consume batch of N messages with `prefetch_count=N`  > re-publish in a loop > move to the other queue > repeat. Pausing is just not consuming, simply blocking (sleep) will do, nothing to implement or to be supported. 3). You might have to clarify the numbers here; if this is IO bound, publish the results back and aggregate this intermediate queue in a separate aggregator/writer service